# Why does Assert.AreEqual() fail for string and DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: c#, date, time, formatting, string-formatting

I have written the following unit test to test date time formatting:

```
using System;
using Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;

namespace MyTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class DateTimeFormatterTests
    {
        [DataTestMethod]
        [DataRow(2, 3, 2017, "en", "Thursday, March 2")]
        [DataRow(2, 3, 2017, "de", "Donnerstag, 2. März")]
        public void Long_date_without_year_should_match_expected(int day, int month, int year, string regionCode, string expected)
        {
            DateTimeFormatterformatter = new DateTimeFormatter("dayofweek month day", new[] { regionCode });
            string actual = formatter.Format(new DateTime(year, month, day));
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the assertion fails with the following error:

```
{"Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Thursday, March 2>. Actual:<‎Thursday‎, ‎March‎ ‎2>. "}
```

Is this because the strings have different encoding?

After converting both strings into byte arrays using UTF8 encoding the content of the byte arrays looks like this:

actual:
    `e2 80 8e 54 68 75 72 73 64 61 79 e2 80 8e 2c 20  e2 80 8e 4d 61 72 63 68 e2 80 8e 20 e2 80 8e 32`

expected:
    `54 68 75 72 73 64 61 79 2c 20 4d 61 72 63 68 20  32`

Comment: What is the type of `actual`?

Comment: Strings doesn't have an encoding, encoding comes into play when you try to convert a string to/from bytes.

Comment: Try comparing them as byte arrays, from `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(actual)` and similar for expected, see what it complains about.

Comment: Encoding both strings into byte arrays (using the mentioned UTF8 encoding) revealed that the byte arrays have different lengths: expected is 17 and actual is 32 bytes long.

Comment: Can you show the two byte array contents in the question, that seems odd as the strings only contain 17 characters and none that requires diacritics or other odd unicode characters, thus for UTF8 encoding each of those characters should result in 1 byte.

Comment: I posted the content of the byte arrays in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The octets `e2 80 8e` show that you have several U+200E characters in the `actual` string. U+200E is a control character for overriding the bi-directional text algorithm and insisting that what follows be written left-to-right, even if it's a case (such as Hebrew or Arabic characters) that would normally be written right-to-left.

The `expected` string does not have them.

Presumably that control character got copied into either your test data or into the actual source of the formatter you are testing. In the latter case, be glad the testing caught it. (Alternatively, maybe it's meant to be there for some reason).

Comment: Since it is the `actual` variable that has these characters it looks like the output of DateTimeFormatter is what contains these codepoints.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen making the last two suggestions (that it's a bug in DateTimeFormatter, or that it is meant to be there) the remaining possibilities.